# Modificando cadena de texto compleja

Tags: python, string, funciones, split

Esta función recibe tres informaciones constantemente, las dos primeras(ora_con y ora_so) son oraciones, estas oraciones contienen la misma cantidad de palabras pero pueden ser diferentes, mientras que (palabras) recibe la cadena que será modificada y siempre será la misma oración, en este caso, recibirá siempre (Max es un humano), supongamos que (ora_con) recibe ("Yo soy Alice una máquina.") y (ora_so) recibe ("Yo soy Max un humano.") ambas tienen misma cantidad de palabras, pero al comparar palabra entre palabra puede ser diferente, entonces la funcion empieza a comparar las palabras entre las oraciones usando una sentencia if, si ("Yo") es diferente de ("Yo") y ("Yo") es igual ("Max") no se cumple el reemplazo de ("Max") por ("Yo"), Nota: Observa la funcion de abajo para que entiendas. pero llegara un momento cuando ("Max") sea diferente de ("Alice") y ("Max") sea igual a ("Max"), osea

```
if so_pala != con_pala and so_pala==tomar:
                    formar+=con_pala+" "
```

entonces la palabra (Max) de la cadena (Max es un humano) deberá ser cambiada por (Alice es un humano), pero resulta que hay dos problemas que no se solucionar, el primero es, resulta que la palabra (es) de (Max es un humano) se elimina o no se agrega porque no esta en las oraciones de comparación, quedando la nueva cadena incompleta como (Alice un humano), el segundo problema es el siguiente, supongamos que la cadena a modificar recibe solo dos cambios, pasa de (Max es un humano) a (Alice es una humano), vemos que falta algunas palabras en ser reemplazadas como (humano) pero al recibir la función otro pal de oraciones de comparación el texto modificado se elimina ¿como podria mantener el texto modificado existente en la función para que se siga modificando? ¿Y como cambiar solo las palabras que no han sido modificadas?

Esta es la funcion en la que necesito ayuda.

```
def interpretar(ora_con,ora_so,palabras,formar=""):
    for con_pala, so_pala in zip(ora_con.split(), ora_so.split()):
        for tomar in palabras.split():
            if so_pala != con_pala and so_pala==tomar:
                formar+=con_pala+" "
```

Este es el código completo, para que puedas probar.

```
###### Intercambio de palabras ###############
##############################################
concepto_de_mi={}
sobre_mi={}
def aprender_uno(oracionex):
    recordal_palsu=conceptos_de_mi
    for palabras in oracionex.split():
        if palabras not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabras]={}
        recordal_palsu=recordal_palsu[palabras]
    return
def aprender_dos(oracionex):
    recordal_palsu=sobre_mi
    for palabras in oracionex.split():
        if palabras not in recordal_palsu:
            recordal_palsu[palabras]={}
        recordal_palsu=recordal_palsu[palabras]
    return
aprender_uno("Yo soy Alice una maquina.")
aprender_uno("Yo soy una chica inteligente.")

aprender_dos("Yo soy Max un humano.")
aprender_dos("Yo soy una buena programadora.")

aprender_uno("Me gusta la programacion.")
aprender_dos("Me gusta la musica.")
Entrada = "Max es un humano."


def interpretar(ora_con,ora_so,palabras,formar=""):
    contar=palabras.split()
    for con_pala, so_pala in zip(ora_con.split(), ora_so.split()):
        for tomar in palabras.split():
            if so_pala != con_pala and so_pala==tomar:
                formar+=con_pala+" "

        print("::::: GENERANDO CADENA ::::::")
        print("Formando: ", formar)
            
            
def profundizar_a(palabra,arbol_con,arbol_so,prefijo_con="",prefijo_so=""):
  if arbol_con=={} and arbol_so=={}:
      print("$ Profundizar en ambos arboles $")
      interpretar(prefijo_con, prefijo_so, palabra)
    
  else:
    for clave,claves in zip(arbol_con,arbol_so):
        profundizar_a(palabra,arbol_con[clave],arbol_so[claves],prefijo_con + " " + clave,prefijo_so + " " + claves)
        

  return


def elaborando(oracion,con_mi,so_mi):
    for con_pala, so_pala in zip(con_mi, so_mi):
            profundizar_a(oracion,con_mi[con_pala],so_mi[so_pala],con_pala,so_pala)
```

**Resumen que creo que es mas simplificado.**

```
La función recibe tres frases.
A - Max es un humano
B - Yo soy Alice una máquina
C - Yo soy Max un humano
```

Yo quiero reconstruir A, en base a B, tomando como ejemplo C, que si la primera palabra de A fuera igual C la primera palabra de A se cambie por la de B.

Comment: no es mejor usar regex???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Estoy aprendiendo, son bastantes, ¿pero crees que realmente me ayuden en todo?

Comment: puede que si eso deberias de preeguntarlo en code reviw bajo el tag de refactory

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez ¿Code review?

Comment: si haca: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: La pregunta es algo extensa. ¿Podrías proporcionar un [mcve]? Una simplificación del problema porque si no resulta bastante inabarcable

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' estoy tratando de encontrarle la vuelta en el chat ;)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' El ejemplo mínimo es ese ignora todo lo que esta debajo de la primera funcion.

Comment: Titulo descriptivo, ejemplo claro... recomiendo leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Al final de la pregunta puse un pequeño resumen para que entiendas mejor.